# How to place an object at the mouse position?

Tags: unity

How can I place a object to position where I clicked in just x,y axis not in z,
I am trying to achieve it with

```
Vector3 mousepos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
object.transform.position = new Vector3(mousepos,mousepos);
```

but it does not seem to work, in fact the object doesn't even move.

Comment: `new Vector3(mouspos,mousepos);` This isn't valid syntax. There's no Vector3 constructor that takes two Vector3s as arguments. What is it you're trying to do with this?

Answer (score -1):

You need to reference the value, not the entire vector.

```
 Vector3 mousepos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
 object.transform.position = new Vector3(mousepos.x,mousepos.y,0);
```

Comment: Or, as the `mousepos` vector is not being recomposed... `object.transform.position = mousepos`

Comment: I was pretty sure that was the case, but couldn't remember what the Z value would be on it

Comment: Depends on your scene. IIRC, a ray is fired into the scene and returns the first point it hits a collider (or the camera's far plane). Ah, [I was wrong](https://answers.unity.com/answers/599100/view.html). As Input.MousePosition will have 0 as the z component, then this method will only ever return the position of the camera.